# How to hide title of push notification when app is closed?

Tags: android, push-notification

In Android, when the device receives a push notification(above version 7.0), I config to display 2 line: **app name, content message**, it work fine when app is open.

```
 String channelId = context.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        int statusBarIcon = R.drawable.ic_app_logo;
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId);
        notificationBuilder
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentTitle(null)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

But I close app, when reveiced a push notification, the notification display with 3 line with: **app name, title (also app name) and content message**.
The config in AndroidManifest is correct.
So, how can I just display a push notification without title all time.
[App close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkpIW.jpg)
[App open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xIQy.jpg)